# Why does "temp" in this piece of code keep the value from the left side when doing right side?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion

```py
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution:
    def pathSum(self, root: TreeNode, targetSum: int) -> List[List[int]]:
        self.resultpath = [] 
        def dfs(node,target,temp):
            if node is None:
                return
            temp.append(node.val)
            print(temp)
            if node.left is None and node.right is None and target == node.val:
                self.resultpath.append(temp)
            dfs(node.left, target-node.val, temp)
            dfs(node.right, target-node.val, temp)
        
        
        dfs(root, targetSum, [])
        return self.resultpath
```

this is really confusing me. For a "Input: root = [5,4,8,11,null,13,4,7,2,null,null,5,1], targetSum = 22"
picture of the tree: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ehvwo.jpg

As this code goes through the recursions, at temp = [5,4,11], dfs(node.left ...) will turn this into [5,4,11,7] but temp is still [5,4,11], so dfs(node.right ...) should turn this into [5,4,11,2] but the 7 from dfs(node.left ...) shows up to make it [5,4,11,7,2].

Why is that? How would I fix this code so it doesn't do that?

Comment: Can you give us the full input and output as it is printed, not your description of it?

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: Why should it not behave this way? See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Instead of mutating `temp` by using its `append` method, pass a *new* list to each recursive call with `dfs(node.left, target - node.val, temp + [node.val]])`. (Less efficient, but easier to follow what it's doing since you aren't mutating any shared state.)

Comment: Any feedback on the answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is quite simple. There is only a single `temp`. You are passing a reference to this single object in all recursive calls, so any mutations in a recursive call to `dfs` will be visible from the calling scope.

The key is to simply copy `temp` every time you make a recursive call.